# iOS Messages Area

Tags: ios, message

I have been looking everywhere but I cannot seem to google it right so I am hoping that someone can help me. Is there any way that I can program something like the "Messages" area in iOS? particularly the iPhone.

Here's a photo of the message area if my explanation was not clear:
http://www.zmetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/iphone-sms.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been lots of blog posts on this subject that you can find with Google. One such detailed explanation is at http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-bubble-ui-iphone-apps

Be aware that Apple has rejected apps for treading too closely on the UI of the Messages app in the best, so proceed with caution: http://www.ipodnn.com/articles/09/09/02/chat.bubble.app.rejection/

Comment: Woah, this is something that I have no knowledge of. Never thought that apple actually has trademark concerns with the chat bubbles. If that is the case, then I will not bother doing this then. Thank you for letting me know this before I made a big mistake of making something like that. Is there a better way of doing this without touching on apple's trademark concerns?

Comment: @Tofu I Am Not A Lawyer, so I have no idea. You need to define both the risks and the rewards for yourself (or for your client).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shaggy Frog. Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
I guess there are many ways to do that. but it is look like a simple UIScrollView and another view that dynamically duplicates itself and formatted as bubble.